# Implementation of ls Command in C

Tags: c, directory, system

I'm currently taking a system programming course and the prof provide us with a sample code for the ls command implementation

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

DIR *dp;
struct dirent *dirp;

if(argc ==1) dp = opendir ("./");

else dp = opendir(argv[1]);

while ((dirp = readdir(dp)) != NULL) printf("%s\n", dirp->d_name);

closedir(dp);
exit(0);
}
```

However, when I tried to run it, it output the message "segmentation fault". Here is a image of what I did [test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIFwO.png)
What is it causing this message?

Comment: In GCC compiler, your program working fine.

Comment: Please post text instead of images of text.

Comment: Did your teacher really provide _this_ faulty and poorly formatted program as a sample ?

Comment: indeed he did and we are suppose to an assignment base on this program

Comment: @MichaelWalz Unfortunately, it's more frequent than you think.

Answer (score 1):

You invoke your program with `./a.out Assignment1.c`.

Then your program does actually a `opendir("Assignment1.c");`. Because `"Assignment1.c"` is a file and not a directory, `opendir` returns `NULL`.

The you naively do `dirp = readdir(dp)` with `dp` being `NULL` which results in a segmentation fault.

You should test the return value of `opendir` and display an error message if it is `NULL`.

Read the [opendir man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/opendir).